# What does "m=" indicate when a Go program receives a SIGABRT

Tags: go, runtime, cgo

My Go program has received a SIGABRT error. Go dumped the error followed by go-routine dump

```
runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7f9b19a2a1f7 m=2
```

What does the value "m=2" indicate. Is it the return value of the pthread_create call?

Comment: here's a similar print statment https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/signal_sighandler.go#L109 here's `m` defined in code https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/runtime2.go#L452 and here's an explanation of what m is https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/HACKING.md